# Highlight cell if its text appears on other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to highlight a cell in a column if its text appears in any cell of other column.
For example, I have a list of items in column A, and I will be writing some of those items in column B. I want those items I have written in column B appear highlighted in column A.

I have tried making a new rule in conditional formatting and using this formula:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)))
```

It says there's an error with the formula.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DavidPostill I have tried this making a new rule in conditional formatting and using this formula =NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(I1,$F:$F,1,FALSE))). When I click OK it says there's an error in the formula.

Comment: Please [edit] the question if you have clarifications. They should not be  done in comments.

Answer (score 0):

The formula you show works perfectly for me both in cells and in the rule for a Conditional Format.

What error is being returned? I would make a best guess at it by thinking you may have a non-US version of Excel which might require a different separator, perhaps the semi-colon rather than the comma. But that's stretching for a reason.

Another thing one might wonder could be whether your version has a function used in the formula or not, but it is incredibly hard to imagine a version that will still run that wouldn't have those three functions available.

Another possibility in the "not enough information to tell" category is perhaps the formula shown is not the precise formula you are using. NOT in the sense of some sea change being made, but rather perhaps you have worksheet names used in the formula and have cleaned those out for us. (Kudos, by the way, if that's so... so annoying to have to test those problems and make up several tabs and so on in order to do so!) If so, it is possible you have typed a worksheet name wrong in an address. If so, I'd say I like setting up these formulas in cells, then copying and pasting into Conditional Formatting rules or Named Range values.

Related is a subtler thing. If you want the formula to act upon A1, and then A2, A3, and so on for a range you give CF-ing, the best way to do that is to work out the test formula in a cell and copy it from the formula editor (F2 line/box). Then select whatever cell you used in the formula as the base cell. Finally, go into CF and follow the normal process pasting the formula you copied into the test rule. As an example, perhaps I work out the formula in cell ABC349876. Who cares? It was just convenient perhaps. I referred to cell A1, as yours does, in the formula. Copied it. SELECTED CELL A1. Went into CF and pasted the formula. Again, while cell A1 was selected. I could have selected cells A1:A20000 if I'd liked but the key element would be cell A1 was active, not some other cell. The rule was relative to the active cell, you see, so to make all the relative references work out, if I want A1 looked at, I either do the above, or I use $A$1 which then limits it from acting on A2, A3, and so on.

If, for instance, you have cell D1 active when you enter the exact formula you give above, Excel will think your test cell is supposed to be three cells left of the cell you expect it to think. Applying that, then, to A1 will have it look for a cell three to its left and there isn't one. ERROR.

That's where passing on precisely what error you receive is very important. In the above case, if would be a #REF! error. Of course, the first thing above would give the same error, but still, very important.

One telling thing though may be that you mention "an error" which phrase one might also use to report an error MESSAGE like (to paraphrase) "There is a problem in this formula." and THAT would really suggest the different separator possibility and possibly simply typos. You get a little help in-cell when that particular message comes up, though it can confuse people, but you get NO help inside CF-ing.

So, checklist: do you have an #ERROR! or an error message? If the former, check your referencing and what cell is active as you enter the formula. If the latter, check the separator and for typos.